# Post Request in REACTJS using hooks

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

I just want a simple insert data using hooks in REACTJS, and every time I submitted a form it already says in response [image]

although in my header request payload, it display my data
[image]

what would probably my error?

here's my post request :

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(props.user)

  const submit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('request url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setUser(json.user))
  }
```

here's the forms :

```
<form onSubmit={submit}>
        <label>Name :</label><input type="text" name="user[Name]" onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, Name: e.target.value })}/>
        <label>Email :</label><input type="email" name="user[Email]" onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, Email: e.target.value })}/>
        <label>Phone :</label><input type="number" name="user[Phone]" onChange={e => setUser({ ...user, Phone: e.target.value })}/>

        <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
      </form>
```

here's my query :

```
function insertUser($con){
    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    if(isset($user)){
        $name = $user->Name;
        $email = $user->Email;
        $phone = $user->Phone;
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone)){
        $query  ="INSERT INTO user(Name, Email, Phone) VALUES('$name','$email','$phone')";
        if(mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con)) )
        {
            $response=array(
                'status' => 201,
                'status_message' =>'User Added Successfully.',
                        'status_name' => $name
            );
        }else
        {
            $response=array(
                'status' => 400,
                'status_message' =>'User insert Failed.'
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response=array(
            'status' => 400,
            'status_message' =>'Request Body Empty.'
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the kind response. All answer will be appreciated cheers

Comment: Add `console.log({ user })` into the `submit` function - let's see what the data is when the request is made. You can edit your question to include that detail.

Comment: You are sending user object in request, so you can access it using $user->user->Name, Try it

Comment: bro @JalvinVohra you save mylife thanks it works.

Comment: @JalvinVohra I'd suggest you add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing user object in request,
You can access it using

```
$user->user->Name
```

Or if you want to convert it to array you can pass `true` as an second argument to the `json_decode` function , Then you can access it as

```
$user['user']['Name']
```

As well.

Happy to help :)